# Конвертация изображения png в jpg C#

Tags: c#, изображения, png, конвертация, jpeg

Здравствуйте. Есть изображение в формате png. Как его правильно переконвертировать в jpg / jpeg ?
Я делаю это так:

```
Image bmp = new Bitmap(path); //путь к картинке
bmp.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Но мне почему-то кажется, что это слишком просто и в случае чего моя конвертация пройдет "криво"...

Comment: Да вроде нормально. Слишком просто — это не так уж плохо :)

Comment: А как вы думаете можно по-другому перекодировать кроме как раскодировать в bitmap и запаковать обратно в нужном формате?

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Просто читал как-то, что, например, при создании иконок такой вот способ будет работать со сбоями. Поэтому и задался подобным вопросом.

Comment: Иконки - это совсем другая тема, они отличаются от обычных файлов с изображением, поэтому простой конвертации там нет, во всяком случае мне еще не попадалось.

Answer (score 3):

В целом ты все делаешь так, только можно бы добавить еще степень сжатия.

```
Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(@"c:\TestPhoto.jpg");
ImageCodecInfo jgpEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder =
    System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;

EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100L);//100L - сжатие. Можно выставить 0L
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
bmp1.Save(@"c:\TestPhotoQualityHundred.jpg", jgpEncoder, 
    myEncoderParameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    // Загружаем картинку.
    System.Drawing.Image image1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);

    //Сохраняем в JPEG .
    image1.Save(@"C:\image_xxx.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);              
    }
}
```

Comment: Формат можно выбрать gif или png, к примеру.